# fix error caused by error in `setup_params()`with y-axis for stacked barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a stacked barplot that looks like so...
[image]

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df = structure(list(Year_Publication = c(1989L, 1994L, 2001L, 2002L, 
                                         2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2007L, 2009L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
                                         2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 
                                         2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 
                                         2022L, 2022L, 2022L), Taxa = c("Cervidae", "Teleostei", "Chondrichtyes", 
                                                                        "Chondrichtyes", "Gastropoda", "Teleostei", "Malacostraca", "Teleostei", 
                                                                        "Teleostei", "Teleostei", "Teleostei", "Teleostei", "Teleostei", 
                                                                        "Teleostei", "Teleostei", "Chondrichtyes", "Teleostei", "Chondrostei", 
                                                                        "Teleostei", "Chondrichtyes", "Decapoda", "Teleostei", "Gastropoda", 
                                                                        "Chondrichtyes", "Chondrostei", "Teleostei", "Bivalvia", "Tetrapoda", 
                                                                        "Teleostei", "Orthoptera", "Chondrichtyes", "Teleostei", "Reptilia", 
                                                                        "Bovidae"), Total_Species_Per_Taxa = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                               1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
                                                                                                               1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), Total_Species_Per_Pub = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -34L))
```

and I have tried this code:

```
ggplot(data = taxa_diversity, aes(x = `Year_Publication`, fill = Taxa)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = `Total_Species_Per_Pub`), stat = "count")

AND

ggplot(data = taxa_diversity, aes(x = `Year_Publication`, y = `Total_Species_Per_Pub`, fill = Taxa)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Error in `geom_bar()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_count()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I know it's an error with the y-axis, because I can get it to work when I don't include an command for the y-axis... but then it gives me a graph with the wrong values on the y-axis.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Change `stat = "count"` to `stat = "identity"`, or better yet, just use `geom_col()`, which is the same as `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 1):

Update (removed basic answer):

Using `geom_col()` we could set `y` in `aes`:

```
my_color <- c("#41859f", "#404040", "#ea9f91","#bfd2d9",
              "#981f26", "#575a7b", "#ce2a0a", "#eddca3",
              "#2c6049", "#41859f", "#404040", "#ea9f91")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data =df, aes(x = `Year_Publication`, y = `Total_Species_Per_Pub`, fill = Taxa)) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_continuous("Year_Publication", labels = as.character(df$Year_Publication), breaks = df$Year_Publication)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=my_color)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]